# Table Column: Show only image

Tags: java, image, swt

I am placing image in a column depending on the status of a boolean value.

```
col = new TableViewerColumn(this, SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(70);
  col.getColumn().setText("Print Status");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
  @Override
  public Image getImage(Object element) {
    if (((AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) element).isSuccess()) {
      return SUCCESS;
    } 
    return FAIL;
    }
  });
```

Here is the `getImage` method

```
private static Image getImage(String file) {
  Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Viewer.class);
  URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/" + file), null);
  ImageDescriptor image = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
  return image.createImage();
}
```

I have tried two ways of creating the image.

```
private static final Image FAIL = getImage("failed.png");
```

And

```
final Image FAIL = new Image(Display.getDefault() ,"D:/Users/workspace/com.aplot/icons/failed.png");
```

In both cases the image does display but there is a text path beside it.  The path looks like it is the array value for that column.

EXAMPLE:

[image] com.aplot.datamodel.ResultsDataModel$ResultsData@9cce9

How can I remove the text and only show the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `getText()` method in `ColumnLabelProvider` and return empty string. if you dont override, it is always display element.toString(). thats why you see toString() value of your data object there.

Comment: I would need a getText() as well as the getImage() for that column?

Comment: Always override both getText() and getImage() and return that values that  you want to display in the table cell.